# CS50 PSET4 Sobel filter - Edges (Border Pixels)

Tags: c, image-processing, cs50, imagefilter, sobel

I have written the below code for CS50 Pset4 for the edge (Sobel filter)

Here is a link for CS50 Pset4 problem description (**Edges part only**): https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/more/

My code that I have written presents a sobel filter image, but my problem is only with border pixel.

Here is my code:

```
// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE imgCopy[height][width];

    float gxRed;
    float gxGreen;
    float gxBlue;

    float gyRed;
    float gyGreen;
    float gyBlue;

    float gRed;
    float gGreen;
    float gBlue;



    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            imgCopy[h][w].rgbtRed = image[h][w].rgbtRed;
            imgCopy[h][w].rgbtGreen = image[h][w].rgbtGreen;
            imgCopy[h][w].rgbtBlue = image[h][w].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }

    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {


            // Top left Corner
            if (h == 0 && w == 0)
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the corner and any pixel outside the corner is considered to be equal zero
                //(The corner pixels does not equal 0 you treat the corner pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = 2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed + imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed;
                gxGreen = 2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen + imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
                gxBlue = 2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue + imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue;

                gyRed = 2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed + imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed ;
                gyGreen = 2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen + imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
                gyBlue = 2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue + imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue;

                gRed = sqrt((gxRed * gxRed) + (gyRed * gyRed));
                gGreen = sqrt((gxGreen * gxGreen) + (gyGreen * gyGreen));
                gBlue = sqrt((gxBlue * gxBlue) + (gyBlue * gyBlue));

                gRed = round(gRed);
                gGreen = round(gGreen);
                gBlue = round(gBlue);

                if(gRed > 255)
                {
                    gRed = 255;
                }
                if(gGreen > 255)
                {
                    gGreen = 255;
                }
                if(gBlue > 255)
                {
                    gBlue = 255;
                }
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
                }

            // Top-right corner
            else if ( h == 0 && w == width - 1 )
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the corner and any pixel outside the corner is considered to be equal zero
                //(The corner pixels does not equal 0 you treat the corner pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = -2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed + -1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed;
                gxGreen = -2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen + -1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen;
                gxBlue = -2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue + -1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue;

                gyRed = 2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed + imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed;
                gyGreen = 2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen + imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen;
                gyBlue = 2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue + imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue;

                gRed = sqrt((gxRed * gxRed) + (gyRed * gyRed));
                gGreen = sqrt((gxGreen * gxGreen) + (gyGreen * gyGreen));
                gBlue = sqrt((gxBlue * gxBlue) + (gyBlue * gyBlue));

                gRed = round(gRed);
                gGreen = round(gGreen);
                gBlue = round(gBlue);

                if(gRed > 255)
                {
                    gRed = 255;
                }
                if(gGreen > 255)
                {
                    gGreen = 255;
                }
                if(gBlue > 255)
                {
                    gBlue = 255;
                }
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Bottom left corner
            else if (h == height - 1 && w == 0 )
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the corner and any pixel outside the corner is considered to be equal zero
                //(The corner pixels does not equal 0 you treat the corner pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = 1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed + 2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed;
                gxGreen = 1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen + 2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
                gxBlue = 1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue + 2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue;

                gyRed = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed + -2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed;
                gyGreen = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen + -2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen;
                gyBlue = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue + -2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue;

                gRed = sqrt((gxRed * gxRed) + (gyRed * gyRed));
                gGreen = sqrt((gxGreen * gxGreen) + (gyGreen * gyGreen));
                gBlue = sqrt((gxBlue * gxBlue) + (gyBlue * gyBlue));

                gRed = round(gRed);
                gGreen = round(gGreen);
                gBlue = round(gBlue);

                if(gRed > 255)
                {
                    gRed = 255;
                }
                if(gGreen > 255)
                {
                    gGreen = 255;
                }
                if(gBlue > 255)
                {
                    gBlue = 255;
                }
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Bottom-right corner
            else if ( h == height - 1 && w == width - 1 )
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the corner and any pixel outside the corner is considered to be equal zero
                //(The corner pixels does not equal 0 you treat the corner pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed + -2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed;
                gxGreen = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen + -2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen;
                gxBlue = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue + -2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue;

                gyRed = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed + -2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed;
                gyGreen = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen + -2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen;
                gyBlue = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue + -2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue;

                gRed = sqrt((gxRed * gxRed) + (gyRed * gyRed));
                gGreen = sqrt((gxGreen * gxGreen) + (gyGreen * gyGreen));
                gBlue = sqrt((gxBlue * gxBlue) + (gyBlue * gyBlue));

                gRed = round(gRed);
                gGreen = round(gGreen);
                gBlue = round(gBlue);

                if(gRed > 255)
                {
                    gRed = 255;
                }
                if(gGreen > 255)
                {
                    gGreen = 255;
                }
                if(gBlue > 255)
                {
                    gBlue = 255;
                }
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Top border pixels
            else if ( h == 0 && (w > 0 && w < width - 1) )
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the border and any pixel outside the border is considered to be equal zero
                //(The border pixels does not equal 0 you treat the border pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = -1 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed + 1 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed;
                gxGreen = -1 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen + 1 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
                gxBlue = -1 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue + 1 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue;

                gyRed = 1 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed + 2 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtRed + 1 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed;
                gyGreen = 1 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen + 2 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtGreen + 1 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
                gyBlue = 1 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue + 2 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtBlue + 1 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue;

                gRed = sqrt((gxRed * gxRed) + (gyRed * gyRed));
                gGreen = sqrt((gxGreen * gxGreen) + (gyGreen * gyGreen));
                gBlue = sqrt((gxBlue * gxBlue) + (gyBlue * gyBlue));

                gRed = round(gRed);
                gGreen = round(gGreen);
                gBlue = round(gBlue);

                if(gRed > 255)
                {
                    gRed = 255;
                }
                if(gGreen > 255)
                {
                    gGreen = 255;
                }
                if(gBlue > 255)
                {
                    gBlue = 255;
                }
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Bottom border pixels
            else if ( h == height - 1 && (w > 0 && w < width - 1) )
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the border and any pixel outside the border is considered to be equal zero
                //(The border pixels does not equal 0 you treat the border pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = -1 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed + 1 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed;
                gxGreen = -1 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen + 1 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
                gxBlue = -1 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue + 1 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue;

                gyRed = -1 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed + -2 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtRed + -1 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed;
                gyGreen = -1 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen + -2 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtGreen + -1 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
                gyBlue = -1 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue + -2 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtBlue + -1 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue;

                gRed = sqrt((gxRed * gxRed) + (gyRed * gyRed));
                gGreen = sqrt((gxGreen * gxGreen) + (gyGreen * gyGreen));
                gBlue = sqrt((gxBlue * gxBlue) + (gyBlue * gyBlue));

                gRed = round(gRed);
                gGreen = round(gGreen);
                gBlue = round(gBlue);

                if(gRed > 255)
                {
                    gRed = 255;
                }
                if(gGreen > 255)
                {
                    gGreen = 255;
                }
                if(gBlue > 255)
                {
                    gBlue = 255;
                }
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Left-side border pixels
            else if ( (h > 0 && h < height - 1) && w == 0 )
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the border and any pixel outside the border is considered to be equal zero
                //(The border pixels does not equal 0 you treat the border pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = 1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed + 2 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtRed + 1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed;
                gxGreen = 1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen + 2 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtGreen + 1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen;
                gxBlue = 1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue + 2 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtBlue + 1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue;

                gyRed = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed + 1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed;
                gyGreen = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen + 1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen;
                gyBlue = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue + 1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue;

                gRed = sqrt((gxRed * gxRed) + (gyRed * gyRed));
                gGreen = sqrt((gxGreen * gxGreen) + (gyGreen * gyGreen));
                gBlue = sqrt((gxBlue * gxBlue) + (gyBlue * gyBlue));

                gRed = round(gRed);
                gGreen = round(gGreen);
                gBlue = round(gBlue);

                if(gRed > 255)
                {
                    gRed = 255;
                }
                if(gGreen > 255)
                {
                    gGreen = 255;
                }
                if(gBlue > 255)
                {
                    gBlue = 255;
                }
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Right-side border pixels
            else if ( (h > 0 && h < height - 1) && w == width - 1 )
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the border and any pixel outside the border is considered to be equal zero
                //(The border pixels does not equal 0 you treat the border pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed + -2 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtRed + -1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed;
                gxGreen = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen + -2 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtGreen + -1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen;
                gxBlue = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue + -2 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtBlue + -1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue;

                gyRed = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed + 1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed;
                gyGreen = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen + 1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen;
                gyBlue = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue + 1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue;

                gRed = sqrt((gxRed * gxRed) + (gyRed * gyRed));
                gGreen = sqrt((gxGreen * gxGreen) + (gyGreen * gyGreen));
                gBlue = sqrt((gxBlue * gxBlue) + (gyBlue * gyBlue));

                gRed = round(gRed);
                gGreen = round(gGreen);
                gBlue = round(gBlue);

                if(gRed > 255)
                {
                    gRed = 255;
                }
                if(gGreen > 255)
                {
                    gGreen = 255;
                }
                if(gBlue > 255)
                {
                    gBlue = 255;
                }
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Middle 3x3 pixels
            else
            {
            gxRed =   (float)((-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (0 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed) + (1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) +
                              (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed)     + (0 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtRed)     + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed) +
                              (-1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (0 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed));

            gxGreen = (float)((-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (0 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen) + (1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen) +
                              (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen)     + (0 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtGreen)     + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen) +
                              (-1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (0 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen));

            gxBlue =  (float)((-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (0 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue) + (1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue) +
                              (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue)     + (0 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtBlue)     + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue) +
                              (-1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (0 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue));

            gyRed =   (float)((-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed) + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) +
                              (0 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed)      + (0 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtRed)      + (0 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed) +
                              (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed)  + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed)  + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed));

            gyGreen = (float)((-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen)  + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen) +
                              (0 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen)      + (0 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtGreen)       + (0 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen) +
                              (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen)  + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen)   + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen));

            gyBlue =  (float)((-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue)  + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue) +
                              (0 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue)      + (0 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtBlue)       + (0 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue) +
                              (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue)  + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue)   + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue));

            gRed = sqrt((gxRed * gxRed) + (gyRed * gyRed));
            gGreen = sqrt((gxGreen * gxGreen) + (gyGreen * gyGreen));
            gBlue = sqrt((gxBlue * gxBlue) + (gyBlue * gyBlue));

            gRed = round(gRed);
            gGreen = round(gGreen);
            gBlue = round(gBlue);

            if(gRed > 255)
            {
                gRed = 255;
            }
            if(gGreen > 255)
            {
                gGreen = 255;
            }
            if(gBlue > 255)
            {
                gBlue = 255;
            }
            image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
            image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
            image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Those are the error messages that i get when i run (check50) to check my code:

:) edges correctly filters middle pixel (**this part is correct**)

:( edges correctly filters pixel on edge
expected "213 228 255\n", not "57 103 174\n"

:) edges correctly filters pixel in corner. (**this part is correct**)

:( edges correctly filters 3x3 image
expected "76 117 255\n21...", not "76 117 255\n57..."

:( edges correctly filters 4x4 image
expected "76 117 255\n21...", not "76 117 255\n57..."

Comment: Ok so i solved the corner pixels issues. It turns out corner pixels does not equal 0 for RBG value. Instead you treat them as a 3x3 matrix for the Gx and Gx value. Same as if you are calculating the Gx and Gy for a middle pixels. but only difference any pixel outside the 3x3 corner matrix is equal 0 (the corner pixel does not equal 0). But still for the border-side pixels i get errors.

Comment: I have updated my code last time i got the corners pixel values wrong, but this time it is correct. Now my only problem is the border pixels. I don't know why it is wrong. I did the same thing as for the corner pixels. It should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: This is by far the longest code I’ve ever seen for implementing a 3x3 convolution... you should really think about how you can reduce code duplication. Write some helper functions, collapse nearly identical code into a single block with a conditional, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: I have added separate functions to my code to get rid of duplicate codes and make code shorter.

Ok i solved it. After a long time staring at it. I noticed that the border pixels should contain 2 rows or columns of the Gx matrix (not just one row or column of the Gx,Gy matrix). And out that 3x3 matrix you will have an imaginary 3 pixels that will be equal zero because there are outside the border of that image.

Anyway here is my full correct code, incase anyone is struggling with this code too.

There are other people who solved this, but their code wasn't clear enough for me. Sadly, I didn't have enough reputation points to comment on there post and ask them some questions because my account is new.

```
void findG();

float gxRed, gxGreen, gxBlue;
float gyRed, gyGreen, gyBlue;
float gRed, gGreen, gBlue;

// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE imgCopy[height][width];

    // Making a copy of image
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            imgCopy[h][w].rgbtRed = image[h][w].rgbtRed;
            imgCopy[h][w].rgbtGreen = image[h][w].rgbtGreen;
            imgCopy[h][w].rgbtBlue = image[h][w].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }

    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {

            // Top left Corner
            if (h == 0 && w == 0)
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the corner and any pixel outside the corner is considered to be equal zero
                //(The corner pixels does not equal 0 you treat the corner pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = 2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed + imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed;
                gxGreen = 2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen + imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
                gxBlue = 2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue + imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue;

                gyRed = 2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed + imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed ;
                gyGreen = 2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen + imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
                gyBlue = 2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue + imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue;

                findG(h,w);
                
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
                }

            // Top-right corner
            else if ( h == 0 && w == width - 1 )
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the corner and any pixel outside the corner is considered to be equal zero
                //(The corner pixels does not equal 0 you treat the corner pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = -2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed + -1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed;
                gxGreen = -2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen + -1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen;
                gxBlue = -2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue + -1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue;

                gyRed = 2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed + imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed;
                gyGreen = 2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen + imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen;
                gyBlue = 2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue + imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue;

                findG(h,w);
                
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Bottom left corner
            else if (h == height - 1 && w == 0 )
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the corner and any pixel outside the corner is considered to be equal zero
                //(The corner pixels does not equal 0 you treat the corner pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = 1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed + 2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed;
                gxGreen = 1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen + 2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
                gxBlue = 1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue + 2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue;

                gyRed = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed + -2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed;
                gyGreen = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen + -2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen;
                gyBlue = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue + -2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue;

                findG(h,w);
                
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Bottom-right corner
            else if ( h == height - 1 && w == width - 1 )
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the corner and any pixel outside the corner is considered to be equal zero
                //(The corner pixels does not equal 0 you treat the corner pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed + -2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed;
                gxGreen = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen + -2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen;
                gxBlue = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue + -2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue;

                gyRed = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed + -2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed;
                gyGreen = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen + -2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen;
                gyBlue = -1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue + -2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue;

                findG(h,w);
                
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Top border pixels
            else if ( h == 0 && (w > 0 && w < width - 1) )
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the border and any pixel outside the border is considered to be equal zero.
                //(The border pixels does not equal 0 you treat the border pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed) + (-1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) ;
                gxGreen = (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen) + (-1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen) ;
                gxBlue = (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue) + (-1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue) ;

                gyRed = (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed);
                gyGreen = (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen);
                gyBlue = (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue);

                findG(h,w);
                
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Bottom border pixels
            else if ( h == height - 1 && (w > 0 && w < width - 1) )
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the border and any pixel outside the border is considered to be equal zero
                //(The border pixels does not equal 0 you treat the border pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed) + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) ;
                gxGreen = (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen) + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen) ;
                gxBlue = (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue) + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue) ;

                gyRed = (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed) + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed);
                gyGreen = (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen) + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen);
                gyBlue = (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue) + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue);

                findG(h,w);
                
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Left-side border pixels
            else if ( (h > 0 && h < height - 1) && w == 0 )
            {
                // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the border and any pixel outside the border is considered to be equal zero
                //(The border pixels does not equal 0 you treat the border pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = (1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed);
                gxGreen = (1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen) + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen);
                gxBlue = (1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue) + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue);

                gyRed = (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed) + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed) + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed);
                gyGreen = (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen) + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen) + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen);
                gyBlue = (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue) + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue) + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue);

                findG(h,w);
                
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Right-side border pixels
            else if ( (h > 0 && h < height - 1) && w == width - 1 )
            {
               // For Gx and Gy values imagine a 3x3 matrix at the border and any pixel outside the border is considered to be equal zero
                //(The border pixels does not equal 0 you treat the border pixel as a 3x3 matrix same as the middle pixels and get the Gx and Gy values for them)
                gxRed = (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (-1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed);
                gxGreen = (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (-1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen);
                gxBlue = (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (-1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue);

                gyRed = (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed);
                gyGreen = (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen);
                gyBlue = (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue);

                findG(h,w);
                
                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

            // Middle 3x3 pixels
            else
            {
                gxRed =   (float)((-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) +
                                  (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed)     + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed) +
                                  (-1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed));

                gxGreen = (float)((-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen) +
                                  (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen)     + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen) +
                                  (-1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen));

                gxBlue =  (float)((-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue)  + (1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue) +
                                  (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue)      + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue) +
                                  (-1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue)  + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue));

                gyRed =   (float)((-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed) + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) +
                                  (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed)  + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed)  + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed));

                gyGreen = (float)((-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) + (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen)  + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen) +
                                  (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen)  + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen)   + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen));

                gyBlue =  (float)((-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue) + (-2 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue)  + (-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue) +
                                  (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue)  + (2 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue)   + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue));
                                  
                findG(h,w);

                image[h][w].rgbtRed = gRed;
                image[h][w].rgbtGreen = gGreen;
                image[h][w].rgbtBlue = gBlue;
            }

        }
    }
    return;
}

void findG(int h ,int w)
{
                gRed = sqrt((gxRed * gxRed) + (gyRed * gyRed));
                gGreen = sqrt((gxGreen * gxGreen) + (gyGreen * gyGreen));
                gBlue = sqrt((gxBlue * gxBlue) + (gyBlue * gyBlue));

                gRed = round(gRed);
                gGreen = round(gGreen);
                gBlue = round(gBlue);

                if (gRed > 255)
                {
                    gRed = 255;
                }
                if (gGreen > 255)
                {
                    gGreen = 255;
                }
                if (gBlue > 255)
                {
                    gBlue = 255;
                }
return;
}
```

Here are the results when you run (check50):

:) edges correctly filters middle pixel

:) edges correctly filters pixel on edge

:) edges correctly filters pixel in corner

:) edges correctly filters 3x3 image

:) edges correctly filters 4x4 image